# Windows Server 2012 Updates not downloading

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a VM on VirtualBox running windows 2012 r2 and I tried to download updates, system connected to update server and told me all updates I need, but when I try to download them its stuck at 0%

Things I have tried:

- ensuring no proxy is needed
- restarting windows update service
- deleting Windows\SoftwareDistribution and restarting windows Update service
- one off installing updates in order of the patches (this got me through the first 5 updates but then I'm stuck again at KB2919355 and even that one wont download solo)

Any further thoughts or insights would be appreciated

Comment: Install the MSU updates on your own after [downloading them](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334)

Comment: that would be not preferable as there are over 100 of them

Comment: You can use WSUSOfffline to automate the process.  You are likely missing required cumulative updates thus preventing you from downloading any updates released after those "required" updates.

Comment: KB2919355 is the April 2014 Update which is required for all new updates. MS released new ISOs which include it and the November 2014 update. So if you reinstall Servers, use the new ISOs.